# iOS tooltip image

Tags: ios, tooltip

I need to implement tooltip in my iOS App. I would like to use [CMPopTipView](https://github.com/chrismiles/CMPopTipView) but with plazn text I would like to have some image also and detect click on this tooltip and perform some action after that. Is this is not possible with CMPopTipView is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write app for iPad you can use `UIPopoverController` with custom background class via property `popoverBackgroundClass` to make it looks like tooltip, and also any view as content for popover.

[UIPopoverController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Popover controllers are only for iPad